# Two way synchronous communication between application instances

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We have an application that manages remote device information.

The remote devices report in to either live or test instances on separate servers (and maybe more in the future).

Sometimes, we need to tell a device reporting to one server to start reporting to the other server (maybe move a badly performing device from live to test for investigation).

By the time the moved device reports in to the other, the server should be "expecting" the device in order that it doesn't bounce it back as reporting to the wrong place.

In effect this means that app1 needs to tell app2 to update its db settings for a particular device and vice versa, so we need some sort of two-way, synchronous communication between the applications (since we need to know that the update was successful before we repoint the device and we need to flag the device as moved on the source server).

I'm looking for a clean way to achieve this with minimum impact on the existing application.

What would be a good approach? WCF? Windows service?

Any guidance on where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: at the simplest - can you not just update the db, and then when the other server gets the client-connect it *checks* the db and finds that yes, it is expected...? more complex but less db-based solutions would be things like message brokers, pub/sub, etc...?

Comment: @MarcGravell fair point - it is the simplest communication solution - but we would then need to store and maintain all app server IPs and DB connection strings across all instances, which is what I was trying to avoid (although I don't think we can avoid storing app server IPs). If you add as reply I can mark it as an accepted answer